# Python traverse over folder, and get file in folder (linux)

Tags: python, linux

I have a folder structure like

```
folder:
    folder:
       file
    folder:
       file
    folder:
       file
    folder:
       file
```

I want to go into each file and alter it, currently I have this:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_dir):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(subdir,file))
```

The problem is, yes this is giving me a string of all the folders/files in the directory... but I cant traverse this its useless to me.

Thanks for any answers

Comment: What's your expected behavior? I didn't get it!

Comment: @MohammadJafari I want to open every file in this folder structure

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I will take a look and test it, and report back

Comment: @Josh Well, you just did! You can `open` the file and alter it, instead of printing its name. Checkout the [`open`'s official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)

Comment: Ok thanks guys, figured it out! <3